# C warnings a concern at runtime?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit

Code that was built using VS 2003 for generating 32 bit binary was built without a single warning.

Same code , without a single code change, Compile and Link is successful using Visual studio 2010 compiler for generating 64 bit binary BUT with below list of warnings.

So, My question is,
Is any warning in the below list a concern at runtime ?

```
pcd.c(248) : warning C4996: 'getenv': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _dupenv_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

pcd.c(377) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'uintptr_t' to 'ULONG', possible loss of data

pcd.c(236) : warning C4100: 'argv' : unreferenced formal parameter


i.c(183) : warning C4100: 'lpReserved' : unreferenced formal parameter

api.c(506) : warning C4996: 'stricmp': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C++ conformant name: _stricmp. See online help for details.

api.c(554) : warning C4310: cast truncates constant value

api.c(719) : warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

api.c(2217) : warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

api.c(2892) : warning C4312: 'type cast' : conversion from 'ULONG_T' to 'HANDLE_T' of greater size

api.c(559) : warning C4702: unreachable code


stdio.h(234) : see declaration of 'fopen'


api.c(2217) : warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

prm.c(681) : warning C4996: 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\stdio.h(234) : see declaration of 'fopen'


host.c(410) : warning C4311: 'type cast' : pointer truncation from 'PVOID_T' to 'unsigned long'


stub.c(138) : warning C4295: 'eye' : array is too small to include a terminating null character


isv.c(372) : warning C4310: cast truncates constant value


chp.c(250) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'SOCKET' to 'ULONG_T', possible loss of data

api.c(665) : warning C4311: 'type cast' : pointer truncation from 'HANDLE_T' to 'LONG'

api.c(1216) : warning C4057: 'function' : 'LPDWORD' differs in indirection to slightly different base types from 'LONG_T *'

hlp.c(1171) : warning C4057: 'function' : 'LPDWORD' differs in indirection to slightly different base types from 'LONG_T *'


neto.c(435) : warning C4057: 'function' : 'PLONG_T' differs in indirection to slightly different base types from 'ULONG_T *'


neto.c(595) : warning C4152: nonstandard extension, function/data pointer conversion in expression

neto.c(2115) : warning C4213: nonstandard extension used : cast on l-value

neto.c(2209) : warning C4057: 'function' : 'int *' differs in indirection to slightly different base types from 'LONG *'

td.c(760) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'uintptr_t' to 'int', possible loss of data

td.c(2104) : warning C4054: 'type cast' : from function pointer 'FARPROC' to data pointer 'PVOID'

msc.c(287) : warning C4133: 'function' : incompatible types - from 'long *' to 'time_t *'


msc.c(1009) : warning C4702: unreachable code


inf.c(400) : warning C4057: 'function' : 'PLONG_T' differs in indirection to slightly different base types from 'ULONG *'

arb.c(166) : warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'LONG_T', possible loss of data

arb.c(226) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'int' to 'CHAR_T', possible loss of data

sl.c(441) : warning C4054: 'type cast' : from function pointer 'int (__cdecl *)(unsigned char *,int,int,void *)' to data pointer 'void *'


pco.c(369) : warning C4057: 'function' : 'PLONG_T' differs in indirection to slightly different base types from 'ULONG_T *'

exit1.c(157) : warning C4295: 'publickey' : array is too small to include a terminating null 


env.c(341) : warning C4267: 'function' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'DWORD', possible loss of data

hook.c(221) : warning C4245: 'return' : conversion from 'int' to 'SOCKET', signed/unsigned mismatch

hook.c(817) : warning C4311: 'type cast' : pointer truncation from 'unsigned char *' to 'int'

tor.c(128) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data


cth.c(1012) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from '__int64' to 'int', possible loss of data


cntrl.c(427) : warning C4996: 'strnicmp': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C++ conformant name: _strnicmp. See online help for details.


api.c(263) : warning C4057: 'function' : 'int *' differs in indirection to slightly different base types from 'LONG_T *'

api.c(706) : warning C4057: 'function' : 'int *' differs in indirection to slightly different base types from 'DWORD *'

ii.c(252) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'time_t' to 'long', possible loss of data
```

Thx

Comment: May be some compiler flags were suppressing these warnings. now that flag is not there. or warnings were there in past, you overlooked

Comment: You were doing unsafe things before (such as using `sprintf`), and the older version of the compiler simply didn't bother warning you about them.

Comment: You are basically casting types that have the same size on x86 but different sizes on x64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three kinds of warnings:

1. Warnings about unsafe/deprecated functions. Some of these warnings you might have gotten before, since those functions were unsafe/nonstandard and maybe deprecated before. However, if you have a look at them and ensure to use them correctly (having in mind that the size of some types changes in 64bit), you can continue to use them. However, I'd try to use standard functions where possible. At the very least you should turn off the warnings individually if you are sure to use the functions correctly.
2. Warnings that should've been there before too, such as "unreferenced parameters", signed/unsigned mismatches, unreachable code and some nasty things like warnings C4295, C4054, C4133. You should fix those, all of them. Some are not very grave (e.g. signed/unsigned mismatch), but also very easy to fix, so fix them just to silence the compiler.
3. Warnings resulting from different sizes in 64bit on Windows with MSVC. In 32 bit, int, long, long long, pointers, size_t etc. have 32 bit size. You could convert them seamlessly, without data losses. However, in 64 bit, long long, size_t and pointers have 64 bit size, while long and int remain 32 bit. Converting them might lose information, especially if pointers are involved. Try to use the correct types, don't use narrowing conversions. That also applies for various typedefs to those types, e.g. PVOID, DWORD and all those typedefs WinAPI uses just to have other names for the same things.

In general: Warnings are there for a reason. Try to silence your compiler as much as possible, by attending each single warning and apply appropiate changes to the code. If you absolutely must do conversions and are sure they won't affect the validity of your program, use explicit casts (i.e. `static_cast` in most cases). By doing so you can be sure you don't miss the single warning that hints at the really stupid mistake you will do one day that completely breaks the whole program and that won't be found until after long days of debugging. I know it's tedious, especially on 32/64 bit dual platform compilation, but its worth the effort in the long term.

Comment: Hello Ame                                                            I did not understand the below warnings.        td.c(2104) : warning C4054: 'type cast' : from function pointer 'FARPROC' to data pointer 'PVOID'                                               sl.c(441) : warning C4054: 'type cast' : from function pointer 'int (__cdecl *)(unsigned char *,int,int,void *)' to data pointer 'void *'                                                                           Please help me

Comment: In both cases you are casting a function pointer to void*. That means, you pass around a designated "pointer to *something*" that indeed points to a function. Any function you pass that pointer to might cast it to something else, e.g. to int* and write to it, or to some function with a completely differnt signature and try to execute it. Both szenarios would lead to undefined behavior. UB means the program crashes if you are lucky. If you are not, *anything* could happen, ranging from wrong results to an automated pizza order, albeit that's unlikely (but not impossible) ;-)

Comment: Hello Arne                                                                    I did not understand this statement:                                      [you pass around a designated "pointer to something" that ....else, e.g. to int* and write to it, or to some function with a completely differnt signature and try to execute it.]                     ########            Here,  i dd not get the meaning of your word "something" here.  Because how else does one  want to use (void *)? Obviously (void *) can be casted to any type pointer, which is at programmer's risk?

Comment: Exactly that's the point of the warning. You cast a function pointer to void*, and that void* can be casted to any type pointer. Consider this: `void* p = &printf; int* ip = (int*)p; *ip = 42; printf("ouch!");` Assigning 42 to `*ip` means writing into the code section of the program, which is very evil. Normally you use void pointers to pass them to some API function. And normally that API function expects that `void*` to point to some data it can read and/or modify, like the `*pi` example. Now if the `void*` actually points to a function and not to some data, it looks very, very suspicious.

Comment: so despite the fact that programmer knows the side effects of using (void *) and program properly, is there still  a chance of evil endings like you gave as an example?

Comment: Yes, there is. Giving something to a function via a `void*` means totally giving your life in the hand of that function's author. You'll have to trust the function to do whatever you think it does. If it does not, you have no diagnostics whatsoever, because you are losing any information you had by that cast to `void*`.

Comment: Example: you have a function `void f(size_t)`. The API you are calling takes a `void*`, expecting a function pointer, e.g. a `void (*)(unsigned)`. In 32 bit Windows, you are doing well, because size_t and unsigned are the same. In 64 bit Windows the API calls that function with an unsigned (32 bit), pushing it on the stack and calling the function. Your function expects a size_t, therefore consumes 64 bit and all bets are of what will happen then. My opinion: don't use `void*` in your code. Ever. If you have API's that expect `void*` arguments, wrap them in well coded functions and use those.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you simply get better at reading the error messages.  They are written in plain language.  You can Google for terms you don't yet understand.

Let's go through a bunch, shall we?

> pcd.c(248) : warning C4996: 'getenv': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _dupenv_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

I'd worry about this only if you call `getenv` while changing variables from another thread.  The problem with these routines is that they rely on global state, which becomes problematic when multiple threads are used.  The newer version is also clearer about who owns what allocation.

> pcd.c(377) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'uintptr_t' to 'ULONG', possible loss of data

Looks suspicious.  Are you doing funky things with casting pointers to integers?  Around the time 64-bit Windows was introduced, they added `ULONG_PTR` for this.

> pcd.c(236) : warning C4100: 'argv' : unreferenced formal parameter
>
> i.c(183) : warning C4100: 'lpReserved' : unreferenced formal parameter

Can safely be ignored or supressed.

> api.c(506) : warning C4996: 'stricmp': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C++ conformant name: _stricmp. See online help for details.

Not terribly concerning.  The name with the underscore might end up making you less portable with *nix systems.

> api.c(554) : warning C4310: cast truncates constant value

Looks suspicious.  Please provide examples.

> api.c(719) : warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
>
> api.c(2217) : warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

These are age-old problems that every decent C programmer should know or understand.  Please do a google search or something to read about buffer overflows and why these functions should be avoided where possible.  Note that while the `_s` names are in the C1x standard, they might not be so common on *nix systems.  There's also `snprintf` and `strncpy` which conform to older standards.

> api.c(2892) : warning C4312: 'type cast' : conversion from 'ULONG_T' to 'HANDLE_T' of greater size

Not sure what `HANDLE_T` is, but in Win32 `HANDLE` is the size of a pointer.  This is pretty bad.  I would suggest `ULONG_PTR` as before.

> api.c(559) : warning C4702: unreachable code

Exactly what it says.

> stdio.h(234) : see declaration of 'fopen'

Did you see it?

> api.c(2217) : warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

Similar to above.

> prm.c(681) : warning C4996: 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\stdio.h(234) : see declaration of 'fopen'

This is another C11 feature that the MS compiler starts recommending.  This one is kind of dubious.  `fopen` is probably OK.  Read documentation as appropriate.

> host.c(410) : warning C4311: 'type cast' : pointer truncation from 'PVOID_T' to 'unsigned long'

Use `ULONG_PTR` or `uintptr_t` instead of `unsigned long`.

> stub.c(138) : warning C4295: 'eye' : array is too small to include a terminating null character

My guess is you declared a string like this:

```
char foo[n] = "blah";
```

Where `n` is a size that is too small to fit the string.  Just remove the integer.

> api.c(1216) : warning C4057: 'function' : 'LPDWORD' differs in indirection to slightly different base types from 'LONG_T *'

`DWORD` and `LONG` are distinct types, and you're taking pointers to one and using it as the other.  This is illegal.  (In this case it won't cause you problems, but you should fix it.)

> neto.c(595) : warning C4152: nonstandard extension, function/data pointer conversion in expression

Hmm, not sure how you did this one.  Maybe you assigned a function pointer into `void *`?  There are several libraries which require this, though it is technically illegal by the standard.

> neto.c(2115) : warning C4213: nonstandard extension used : cast on l-value

My guess is you did something like this:

```
*(char*)foo = bar;
```

Illegal.

> neto.c(2209) : warning C4057: 'function' : 'int *' differs in indirection to slightly different base types from 'LONG *'

Similar situation to using `PDWORD` and `LONG` interchangeably.

> td.c(2104) : warning C4054: 'type cast' : from function pointer 'FARPROC' to data pointer 'PVOID'

Similar to neto.c, line 595.

Comment: For your statement: "I'd worry about this only if you call getenv while changing variables from another thread."                             Before _dupenv_s was introduced, How getenv functionality was performed from multiple threads? Because i gues threads evolved more early than _dupenv_s?

Comment: For your request: api.c(554) : warning C4310: cast truncates constant value
Looks suspicious. Please provide examples.

Comment: #define a    (SHORT_T)0x8000          
#define b    (SHORT_T)0x4000


api.c Line #554--- func(1618, a|b, NULL, 0, "abc");


void func( ULONG_T a, SHORT_T b,
    PUCHAR_T c, ULONG_T d, ... )
{
......
}

Answer (score 5):

Yes:

I see several that will cause undefined behavior.

All warnings should be considered logical errors (in at least your thinking) and should be looked at and made silent. Either by explicitly changing the code / by by using compiler directives to silence the warnings (then write a long comment as to why you quietened the warning, this also shows it has been looked at deliberately).

A quick scan of the ones I would check first (dupes removed).

These definitely sound bad:

```
stub.c(138) : warning C4295: 'eye' : array is too small to include a terminating null character
exit1.c(157) : warning C4295: 'publickey' : array is too small to include a terminating null
```

These may be bad:

```
api.c(554) : warning C4310: cast truncates constant value

chp.c(250) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'SOCKET' to 'ULONG_T', possible loss of data

api.c(1216) : warning C4057: 'function' : 'LPDWORD' differs in indirection to slightly different base types from 'LONG_T *'

neto.c(2209) : warning C4057: 'function' : 'int *' differs in indirection to slightly different base types from 'LONG *'

td.c(760) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'uintptr_t' to 'int', possible loss of data

msc.c(287) : warning C4133: 'function' : incompatible types - from 'long *' to 'time_t *'

arb.c(166) : warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'LONG_T', possible loss of data

arb.c(226) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'int' to 'CHAR_T', possible loss of data

api.c(665) : warning C4311: 'type cast' : pointer truncation from 'HANDLE_T' to 'LONG'
```

These I would not leave in the code but are probably benign:

```
api.c(559) : warning C4702: unreachable code

td.c(2104) : warning C4054: 'type cast' : from function pointer 'FARPROC' to data pointer 'PVOID'
```

Comment: Benign mean orphan, i gues, why this is orphan?                             td.c(2104) : warning C4054: 'type cast' : from function pointer 'FARPROC' to data pointer 'PVOID'

Comment: @user1787812: Benign means not a health problem. See: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/benign definition 3. A void* is supposed to be able to hold all pointers including function pointers (though not member pointers) I assume PVOID is void* but because this is an assumption I would fix the warning.